# recover data from ddrescue img fails

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk, ddrescue

After seeing some corrupted partition I did recovered whole disk using ddrescue and file is imagefile.img

```
 ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sda imagefile.img imagefile.log
```

now I want to recover some folders from one of the partitions.
the problem is that I can't access into partitions and it has some imagefile.img1 when i use parted in imagefile it has

```
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

Can I somehow access to that partition and extract important information?

imagefile.log contents:

```
# Mapfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.23
# Command line: ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sda /media/user/F6EA8FBAEA8F75A1/imagefile.img /media/user/F6EA8FBAEA8F75A1/imagefile.log
# Start time:   2020-07-31 05:14:39
# Current time: 2020-07-31 05:14:39
# Finished
# current_pos  current_status  current_pass
0x4A85D50000     +               1
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x4A85D56000  +
```

Interesting thing: It somehow has 465 disk which isn't even hardware size.

```
sudo fdisk -lu imagefile.img
Disk cdisk.img: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x216233ce

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
imagefile.img1       2048 976773119 976771072 465.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

it is the disk inside disk probably. but I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Are you use that you are using `ddrescue` correctly?  Can you edit your question to include the log?   Do you think that maybe your hard drive is dying or corrupted - explaining both the source of the original problem and the reason why you can't fix it

Comment: i can still access to those partitions so hard drive probably isn't dying. all health checks show that health is okay.  Just need to restore something from that partitions. as for logs I don't have one as it was finished okay. one thing is that I had stopped ddrescue and resumed for several times but it should not be an issue as for partition it works fine

Comment: `imagefile.log` has nothing?  If you can access all partitions and "everything works fine", you should be able to access data, right?

Comment: added imagefile.log contents. I can access all partitions to the hardware not in the image and I need some folders from image.

Comment: You should be able to mount an image.  Have you tried this?

Comment: yes I have mounted it with `sudo mount -o loop imagefile.img recovery`
It says: `mount: /media/user/F6EA8FBAEA8F75A1/recovery: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.` 
btw same recovery was mountpoint for partition and it accessed fine

Comment: Hmmm... It looks to me that you copied the problems from the original to your "rescue".  It's not too surprising considering that `dd` copies data indiscriminately, and also if the original data was unreadable due to corruption, there would not have been a way for any recovery tools to read it either.

Comment: I get that dd copies data indiscrimilately but how come that I can access original hardware? will partition table repair help?

Comment: I have updated it with fdisk response. @Nmath Do you have an idea what is this img1 file? as I see it is disk inside a disk.